# JSON, unable to decode in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm currently dumping a call to an API which returns JSON data:

```
<?php dd($info)?>
```

Which dumps

```
{#39751 ▼
+"categories": array:19 [▼
0 => {#1065 ▼
  +"category_name": "Block"
  +"category_description": "Description details"
  +"products": array:24 [▼
    0 => {#1070 ▼
      +"price": {
      "01":"100.00"
      }
      +"product_info": {
        "product_code": 123,
        "product_type":{
            "quantity": 2
        }
      }
    }
    1 => {#1070 ▼
      +"price": {
      "01":"200.00"
      }
      +"product_info": {
        "product_code": 112,
        "product_type":{
            "quantity": 3
        }
      }
    }
1 => {#1065 ▼
  +"category_name": "Flat"
  +"category_description": "Description details"
  +"products": array:24 [▼
    0 => {#1070 ▼
      +"price": {
      "01":"100.00"
      }
      +"product_info": {
        "product_code": 221,
        "product_type":{
            "quantity": 2
        }
      }
    }
    1 => {#1070 ▼
      +"price": {
      "01":"200.00"
      }
      +"product_info": {
        "product_code": 223,
        "product_type":{
            "quantity": 3
        }
      }
    }
```

But when I do:

dd(json_decode($info))

It just returns null and I can't seem to access it.

Is there an apparent reason why I can dump this but not decode it in the blade?

UPDATE:

Trying originally to test by looping/accessing:

```
foreach($info as $info->categories) { 
  $category_name = $info->categories['category_name']; 
  dd($category_name);
}
```

Comment: Check if json decode failed [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: Your first `dd()` shows it's _not_ encoded. Why are you trying to decode it?

Comment: @Dharman it says it failed to parse it

Comment: @Sammitch I was trying to access it in a loop and couldn't so I thought I'd need to decode it. How would I properly loop/access elements in it as is then?

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Sammitch I just posted an update with my original test of looping/accessing it

Comment: That loop goes to nowhere....

Comment: @Dharman I only dump the category name to see if it was being accessed but it still prints NULL. I'm not trying to print each one but just access it and print a value so that I know I'm where I need to be in the array

Comment: Try to loop like this: `foreach($info->categories as $category){`

Comment: Yes that got it @Dharman ! Thanks, So I guess for each nested level I can just do another loop like that then

Comment: Make sure your `error_reporting` is turned on/up so you actually see the relevant error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($info as $info->categories) { 
    $category_name = $info->categories['category_name']; 
    dd($category_name);
}
```

instead go for

```
foreach($info->categories as $category) {
    $category_name = $category['category_name']; 
    dd($category_name);
}
```

Laravel is a framework helping you with the common request/response lifecycle of web applications. Doing so, it usually handles serialization and deserialization of objects as well as the request payload itself if possible. So if it receives a JSON encoded payload it converts it into an array or if you want so it even can create objects from the array, e.g. you post a json encoded data from any API and want to convert it into your Category entity. Best practice for this is btw. using a DTO which builds a layer between the data used for communication between layers and the actually persisted business object.

To pass an object, e.g. you category model/entity, to the view you just need to assign it as it is.

Being aware, that blade is processed on the server, it's running within PHP so, there's no need at all to decode/encode. Only one case would be if you actually want to display a representation of JSON in your frontend.

Please be aware that dd stands of dump and die, so the application doesn't continue.